# Is there a way to uninstall VScode from the anaconda distribution and then reinstall it as a "fresh start"?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

Recently, I've come across more and more problems regarding VScode. Mainly it has to do with importing things, linting working incorrectly, and so much more. Is there any way to sort of reinstall the anaconda version of VScode so that its kind of a factory default? I'd really appreciate any guidance with this. Thank you!

Comment: you tried doing conda "remove pakcage-name" and "conda install package-name"?

Comment: Through terminal?

Comment: yes.try this link "https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to reset VS Code from the Python extension's perspective is to erase your user settings and any relevant workspace settings related to the extension. You can then uninstall the Python extension, restart VS Code, and then install the Python extension again.